How to get text when it is after a class or span tag?
I have been able to get the information I want, using Scrapy, to get information on car models, types, features etc.
However, I cannot get the price. All the other information is in stuff like a class, h4 element etc. But this is after  the class and in its own selection. I have been using .css to get the info. But can not figure out how to get this text.
There is multiple records on the page. Using xpath the next car goes up by one in the xpath tag
/html/body/main/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div\[2\]/div\[3\]/div\[**49**\]/div/div\[2\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div/span/text()

/html/body/main/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div\[2\]/div\[3\]/div\[**50**\]/div/div\[2\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div/span/text()

Here is the URL :https://www.stoneytrailmazda.com/vehicles/new/?view=grid&sc=new

Any advice on what would work would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to use xpath, classes, Scrapy, Scrapy-Playwright but I can not figure it out.
Below is the code so far:
class ScrapingClubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stonymazda"
    allowed_domains = ["stoneytrailmazda.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.stoneytrailmazda.com/vehicles/new/"
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={"playwright": True})

    def parse(self, response):
        # iterate over the product elements
        for product in response.css(".vehicle-card__details"):
            # scrape product data
            url = product.css("a").attrib["href"]
            Model = product.css(".vehicle-card__title::text").get()
            Price = product.css("#ae-skip-to-content > div > div > div.pl-sm.pr-sm > div > div.col.primary-col.dealertrack-vehicle-wrapper > div.row.grid-row > div:nth-child(50) > div > div.vehicle-card__details > div.price-block > div > div > div > div > span::text").get()
            #price = product.css("h5::text").get()

            # add the data to the list of scraped items
            yield {
                "url": url,
                "Model": Model,
                #"name": name,
                "Price": Price

